# How to convert monthly values to nan?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
       CODE      DATE     TMAX  TMIN   PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  32.6  23.4  0.0
1      000130 1991-01-02  31.2  22.4  0.0
2      000130 1991-01-03  32.0   NaN  0.0
3      000130 1991-01-04  32.2  23.0  0.0
4      000130 1991-01-05  30.5  22.0  0.0
      ...        ...   ...   ...  ...
10865  000130 2020-12-31   NaN   NaN  NaN
10866  000132 1991-01-01  35.2   NaN  0.0
10867  000132 1991-01-02  34.6   NaN  0.0
10868  000132 1991-01-03  35.8   NaN  0.0
10869  000132 1991-01-04  34.8   NaN  0.0
```

For PP column i need to convert monthly PP data to NaN only if there is 3 or more NaN values in a month (not necesary consecutive). For example: If January 1991 have 3 NaN values in column PP (not necesary consecutive), all January 1991 values of column PP must be converted to NaN. Same with every month in every year. I need to do this by CODE. So im thinking in first use df.groupby('CODE'). But im not sure how to do it. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Series that calculates the number of `NaN` values with each Code x Year-month group, then you can use that to `mask` the original column where it's `>=3`.

Here's some sample data where [000130, 1991-01] should be NaN'd and [000130, 2020-12] and [000132, 1991-01] remain the same.

```
### Sample Data

       CODE      DATE     TMAX  TMIN   PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  32.6  23.4  NaN
1      000130 1991-01-02  31.2  22.4  NaN
2      000130 1991-01-03  32.0   NaN  0.0
3      000130 1991-01-04  32.2  23.0  NaN
4      000130 1991-01-05  30.5  22.0  0.0
10865  000130 2020-12-31   NaN   NaN  0.0
10866  000132 1991-01-01  35.2   NaN  0.0
10867  000132 1991-01-02  34.6   NaN  NaN
10868  000132 1991-01-03  35.8   NaN  0.0
10869  000132 1991-01-04  34.8   NaN  0.0
```

---

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

s = df['PP'].isnull().groupby([df['CODE'], df['DATE'].astype('datetime64[M]')]).transform('sum')

df['PP'] = df['PP'].mask(s.ge(3))

#         CODE       DATE  TMAX  TMIN   PP
#0      000130 1991-01-01  32.6  23.4  NaN
#1      000130 1991-01-02  31.2  22.4  NaN
#2      000130 1991-01-03  32.0   NaN  NaN
#3      000130 1991-01-04  32.2  23.0  NaN
#4      000130 1991-01-05  30.5  22.0  NaN
#10865  000130 2020-12-31   NaN   NaN  0.0
#10866  000132 1991-01-01  35.2   NaN  0.0
#10867  000132 1991-01-02  34.6   NaN  NaN
#10868  000132 1991-01-03  35.8   NaN  0.0
#10869  000132 1991-01-04  34.8   NaN  0.0
```